# There is unknown field "container" in Tekton

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I'm interested in Tekton these days.

However there are some issue when I implement `Task` with java fabric8.tekton apis.

There exist api which is adding steps in spec in units of container(`withContainer`) in `TaskBuilder` class.

However I got error message in rune time like below,
[image]

Can I get some advices?

**Tekton version -  v0.10.1**

I used packages like below:

**io.fabric8:kubernetes-client:4.7.1**

**io.fabric8:tekton-client:4.7.1**

Here is my complete test code.

```
package com.example.tekton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Container;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.ContainerBuilder;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.BaseClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.ConfigBuilder;
import io.fabric8.tekton.client.TektonClient;
import io.fabric8.tekton.client.DefaultTektonClient;
import io.fabric8.tekton.client.handlers.TaskHandler;
import io.fabric8.tekton.client.handlers.TaskRunHandler;
import io.fabric8.tekton.pipeline.v1alpha1.ArrayOrString;
import io.fabric8.tekton.pipeline.v1alpha1.Task;
import io.fabric8.tekton.pipeline.v1alpha1.TaskBuilder;
import io.fabric8.tekton.pipeline.v1alpha1.TaskRun;
import io.fabric8.tekton.pipeline.v1alpha1.TaskRunBuilder;
import io.fabric8.tekton.pipeline.v1alpha1.TaskRefBuilder;

public class DefaultKubernetesTest {

public Task getTask() {
  Container con = new ContainerBuilder()
                        .withNewImage("ubuntu")
                        .withNewName("echo-hello-world")
                        .addNewCommand("echo")
                        .addNewArg("hello jinwon world")
                        .build();

    Task task = new TaskBuilder()
        .withApiVersion("tekton.dev/v1alpha1")
        .withKind("Task")
        .withNewMetadata()
            .withName("echo-hello-world-test")
        .endMetadata()
        .withNewSpec()
            .addNewStep()
                .withContainer(con)
            .endStep()
        .endSpec()
        .build();

        return task;
}

public TaskRun getTaskRun() {
    TaskRun taskRun = new TaskRunBuilder()
    .withNewMetadata()
        .withName("taskrun")
        .endMetadata()
    .withNewSpec()
        .withTaskRef(new TaskRefBuilder().withName("echo-hello-world-test").withApiVersion("tekton.dev/v1alpha1").withKind("Task").build())
    .endSpec().build();
    return taskRun;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigBuilder config = new ConfigBuilder();
    DefaultKubernetesTest kubeTest = new DefaultKubernetesTest();
    String username = "testUser";
    String password = "testPwd";

    config = config.withMasterUrl("https://192.168.6.236:6443");
    config = config.withUsername(username);
    config = config.withPassword(password);
    Config kubeConfig = config.build();

    try (DefaultTektonClient test = new DefaultTektonClient(kubeConfig)) {
        Task task = kubeTest.getTask();
        TaskRun taskRun = kubeTest.getTaskRun();
        test.tasks().inNamespace("test").create(task);
        test.taskRuns().inNamespace("test").create(taskRun);
        test.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you provide complete code

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Sure. I will add the code.

Comment: Which tekton version are you trying this on? Fabric8 Kubernetes Client's tekton model is at 0.9.0 presently

Comment: @RohanKumar Thanks for reply. As I said in the question, I used tekton model at 0.10.1. I'll try with 0.9.0 then.

Comment: @RohanKumar I tried with tekton 0.9.0 version, but I got same error. Can I get more advices?

Comment: Hmm, Could you please file a bug report on https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client . I'll try to look into these whenever I get time

Comment: @RohanKumar Yep. I'll make an issue related to this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tekton ships with an admission controller, which validates the CRD specs before allowing them into the cluster.  Because the project is still in alpha, its moving quite fast. Fabric8 may be templating out K8s objects against a different spec from what has been installed on your cluster.  You should be able to validate the spec version used in Fabric8 and remove all the Tekton objects in your cluster and re-apply them at a specific version.